# JQuery get value of textarea using name

Tags: jquery, textarea

I cannot seem to get the value from a textarea using the name.  I have tried the following but neither work.

```
jQuery( 'textarea[name=address]' ).val();

jQuery( 'textarea[name=address]' ).text();
```

Please see the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e22uq5ds/.

Comment: its working http://jsfiddle.net/e22uq5ds/1/

Comment: @LeeTee Try with find() function

Comment: @LeeTee your jsfiddle does not include the code in the question.

Comment: Strange as these all work in JSfiddle but are not working on my actual form.  There is too much code to post on here. It must be something else thats causing it not to work

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery('textarea[name="address"]').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

You should use find() function:

jQuery:

```
var textAreaByName = $(this).find('textarea[name="nameTextarea"]').text();
alert(textAreaByName);   //You get: "Example"
```

HTML:

```
<textarea name="nameTextarea" type="text">Example</textarea>
```

I tested it, that it works well :)

Comment: There's no need for `find`.  Sure it works, but it's not needed unless there's something else in OPs code that is not included.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$('textarea[name="address"]').val();
```

or

```
jQuery('textarea[name="address"]').val();
```